# Compute the limit of the sequence ${\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to compute the limit of this sequence ${\textstyle\sum_{k=1}^n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. First I was thinking about some Riemann sum and and forced the $n^{2}$ outside the square root but the function was not so pleasant.

Comment: Does this series converge?

Comment: @SeanNemetz Yes.

Comment: @C.Cristi please refrain from calling $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ a *series*. This is merely a sequence. A series would be $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ where $a_k$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yeah, you're right. My bad..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about squeezing ?

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

The outer terms both go to $1$.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. Can you tell me more about squeezing theorem and how to use it when you're dealing with this kind of fractions?

Comment: @C.Cristi A sum of $n$ terms is less than $n\cdot \text{biggest summand}$ and greater than $n\cdot \text{smallest summand}$. This is a general principle that doesn't necessarily yield sharp bounds. For your problem though, it's sufficient.